# Change texture of SKNode that is an SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

In a game I'm making I can get the node the user is touching with

```
var node = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)
```

However, this gets me an SKNode (even if the node the user touches is an SKSpriteNode) and I cannot use node.texture to change its texture. How can I change that SKNode to an SKSpriteNode or change its texture? (Actions won't work here because I need to pause the scene and they won't work when the scene is paused).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting is what you are looking for.

For instance:

If you are sure that the casting will be successful and your SKNode() is actually a SKSpriteNode, you can do the following:

```
let s = SKNode()
let ss: SKSpriteNode = (s as? SKSpriteNode)!
```

However, it is always better to use the optional specially in casting:

```
let ss2: SKSpriteNode? = s as? SKSpriteNode
```